# В чём отличие enum class от enum struct?

Tags: c++, enum

В чём отличие `enum class` от `enum struct`?

Comment: Просто классы и структуры отличаются только секциями и наследованием по умолчанию, а раз их нет в enum, то скорее всего ничем. Обычно когда enum объявляют даже class | struct не пишут

Comment: `enum class` эквивалентно `enum struct`, но не эквивалентно `enum`.  см. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations :  `the keywords class and struct are exactly equivalent`